# Window confirm OK/Cancel strange behavior in Dialog Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(I made a post about this before but I'll try to be a little more clear in this one.)

I'm having some problem with a windows.confirm box. My click-event opens a jquery dialog-box and loads a list of objects. Every object has a deletebutton which deletes and sends back an updated list (via Django view).

Im trying to put a OK/Cancel confirm before the delete. It works one time. The problem im having is that the next time i open the dialog, click delete i have to press OK/Cancel two times, then three times and so on..

Any ideas? (I've tried also else return false)

```
$("#mylist").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
      width: 800,
      height: 530,
      resizable: false,
      title: "Dialog Title",
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true
    });

$("#dialog").on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var val = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
  if(val == true) {
     $("#dialog").load($(this).attr("href"));
  } 
});
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not attaching the `click` event more than once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try closing the first function before you define the second:

```
$("#mylist").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
      width: 800,
      height: 530,
      resizable: false,
      title: "Dialog Title",
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true
    });
});

$("#dialog").on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var val = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
  if(val == true) {
     $("#dialog").load($(this).attr("href"));
  } 
});
```

Comment: Good catch. Without closing the first, you are re-binding an additional time after each click.

Comment: Yes I think this works! Damn, I really am an illeterate on this... Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is that the click event which contains the confirm is inside the #mtlist click event.

Try this:

```
$("#mylist").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   $('#dialog').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
   width: 800,
   height: 530,
   resizable: false,
   title: "Dialog Title",
   autoOpen: true,
   modal: true
  });
});

$("#dialog").on("click", ".delete", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var val = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
if(val == true) {
  $("#dialog").load($(this).attr("href"));
} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$("#mylist").click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog').dialog('destroy').remove();
    $('#dialog').load($(this).attr('href')).dialog({
      width: 800,
      height: 530,
      resizable: false,
      title: "Dialog Title",
      autoOpen: true,
      modal: true
    });
```

If it breaks everything try without the remove